# git file upload/publish taking too long

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I am new to github and performing my first commit via Visual Studio UI (not using terminal). Everyting worked fine , status bar showing most of my code base uploaded successfully with no issues reported. It is now stuck at the same position with no errors reported. The files sizes are huge but most of the website is already uploaded (approx 3 quarters)

I looked around for a solution , one suggested increasing the

`http.postBuffer size`
using the following command in the terminal: `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

I did and did a quick check and indeed it was `524288000`

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this? I am also about to disconnect as its been waiting here for a while, will disconnecting mean i will have to restart the committ from scratch or will it retain most of the files committed thus far

Comment: The [Git FAQ outlines that you should not need to use `http.postBuffer`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer).  Are you using an antivirus or firewall other than the default, or a proxy or TLS middlebox of any sort?

Comment: turns out i was posting to the wrong repository - my lesson here is to use less UI of editors and just focus on learning terminal command lines